# Sum of an arithmetic progression if each number is mod by $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

I have reduced a part of a programming task to sum of an arithmetic expression where each term is mod by $n$, that is:

$a\%n+(a+d)\%n+(a+2d)\%n+...+(a+md)\%n$

Right now what I have is:

```
for(i=a;i<=a+m*d;i+=d)
    sum+=i%d
```

I was wondering if there is a direct formula to calculate this instead of running a loop?

**Edit 1:** $1<n<10$, $1\leq m\leq10^{18}$, $0\leq d\leq10^{9}$

**Edit 2:** If not for any $n$ is it possible to do this without a loop for $n=9$? Any maths trick to get the answer for this particular case?

Comment: Is $m$ much larger than $\frac{n}{\gcd(n, d)}$?

Comment: @Element118 please check edit 1

Comment: @Macavity $(a+b)\%n=(a\%n+b\%n)\%n$. Isn't mod of whole on the RHS above necessary? What you suggest is $(a+b)\%n=a\%n+b\%n $. Also please check edit 2.

Comment: @Macavity No I don't want the mod of whole thing but what you suggested (breaking down each term into one with $a$ and one with the $d$) i.e. $(a+d)\%n=a\%n+d\%n$ so that you can just loop through the $d$ terms ... I feel is wrong. Because it should be  $(a+d)\%n=(a\%n+d\%n)\%n$ instead?

Comment: I am reasonably clear now that I don't quite follow what you want :(

Comment: You can use a cycle-finding algorithm. It runs in $O(n)$ time since $a+kd$ repeats with period at most $n$. Then all you need to find out is how many times $a+kd$ cycles through the numbers less than $n$. However, you still need to consider the case when $a, d<0$ as modulus returns weird values (by weird, I mean negative) when supplied with negative arguments.

Comment: @Element118 I figured that out and it worked. :) Anyways thanks for the answer. Can you write it as an answer instead of comment so that I can accept it?

Comment: If there are both positive and negative terms in the series, the answer depends on the programming language. For Java and modern versions of C/C++, `x%n` produces a negative value if `x` is negative and `n` is positive, but Python will always produce a positive result. (In a very old C standard, I seem to recall the answer was implementation-dependent.) The syntax of the sample code in the question seems to imply a language of the C/C++/Java persuasion, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative answer which does not require cycle-finding techniques, and takes care of negative numbers. Since $n$ is small, we can write a small for loop to evaluate the first $n$ terms.

Since $$a+kd\equiv a+(n+k)d\mod n$$
This implies that the sequence is somewhat periodic. (It might not be periodic as there are negative and positive numbers.)

If the sequence is completely non-positive or non-negative, i.e $a(a+md)\geq0$, then we can separate the sequence into $\left\lfloor\frac{m+1}{n}\right\rfloor$ groups of $n$ and at most $n-1$ extra terms, which can be evaluated in $O(n)$.

Otherwise, we can use ternary search to find the value $k$ which minimizes $|a+kd|$, or just take $k=\left\lfloor-\frac{a}{d}\right\rfloor$, since $d\neq 0$ (credit to [David K](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/139123/david-k)), and split the sequence around that term to form a non-positive sequence and a non-negative sequence. Each sequence takes $O(n)$ time to evaluate, so the sum of the entire sequence can be evaluated in $O(n)$.

Comment: Ternary search? If $m>0$ and $a(a+md)<0$, then $d\neq0$ and $a/d < 0$; take $\lfloor -a/d \rfloor$, and this will tell you how many terms of the series have the same sign as $a$.